# Creating a table structure from DB that contains cell value, column number, and row number all in the same row?

Tags: postgresql, pivot

So I've been racking my brain over creating a table like structure from a database that has all the elements in rows. The table looks as follows:

| Cell | single_value | frame_column | frame_row | rowspan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4973 | Sub_output_1 | 208 | 3108 | 3 |
| 5006 | Sub_output_2 | 208 | 3111 | 8 |
| 4970 | Output_1 | 207 | 3108 | 13 |
| 5006 | target_1 | 209 | 3108 | 1 |
| 5007 | target_2 | 209 | 3109 | 1 |
| 5008 | target_3 | 209 | 3110 | 1 |
| 5028 | target_5 | 209 | 3111 | 1 |
| 5021 | target_4 | 209 | 3112 | 1 |
| 5041 | target_6 | 209 | 3113 | 1 |

I need the columns to be structured as the following table, respecting the duplications number of the column 'ROWSPAN'

| Output | Sub_output | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_1 | target_1 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_1 | target_2 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_1 | target_3 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_4 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_5 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_6 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_7 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_8 |
| Output_1 | Sub_output_2 | target_9 |

I've tried using case when, but the rows don't align.

I'm running PostgreSQL 12.15 (Ubuntu 12.15).

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
create table test (
  cell int, single_value varchar(200), frame_column int, frame_rows int, rowspan int);
  
insert into test (cell, single_value, frame_column, frame_rows, rowspan)
VALUES 
(4973, 'Sub_output_1', 208, 3108, 3),
(5006, 'Sub_output_2', 208, 3111, 8),
(4970, 'Output_1', 207, 3108, 13),
(5006, 'target_1', 209, 3108, 1),
(5007, 'target_2', 209, 3109, 1),
(5008, 'target_3', 209, 3110, 1),
(5028, 'target_4', 209, 3111, 1),
(5021, 'target_5', 209, 3112, 1),
(5041, 'target_6', 209, 3113, 1)
;
```

Comment: It remains unclear how the given input leads to the given output. Please clarify. And always disclose your Postgres version. Ideally provide a fiddle to work with.

Comment: Sorry for that one, added it in the question.

Comment: I still don't get what you are asking.

Comment: I'm trying to pass from the first table, where all the values are in one single column, to the 2nd table, where the columns are all populated by the values of the first table's _singlevalue_. And the values are allocated in accordance with the names of the new columns (Output, Sub_output, Target).